# How to connect to localhost of headless server (for Syncthing)

Tags: networking, ssh, localhost, headless

I was unable to use

```
ssh pi@raspberrypi.local -L 8384:raspberrypi.local:8384 -N
```

to connect to `localhost:8384` when installing [Syncthing](https://docs.syncthing.net/intro/getting-started.html). This was odd because I successfully connected to another service right before with that line (on another port).

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is also of course possible to change `syncthing`'s config in `~/.config/syncthing/config.xml` to bind the webGUI to some other IP than `120.0.0.1`.

After changing the config use `sudo systemctl restart syncthing@USER.service` with `USER` beeing the user from the `HOME` folder to restart the service.

Answer (score 1):

It worked with `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local -L 8384:127.0.0.1:8384 -N`.

Also, what is maybe interesting to know: The process can be put into background with

```
syncthing &
```

It will still print output to the console but by canceling this output with `CTRL-C` the background process will not be canceled and is still doing fine.